# Reconnecting BLE

Tags: javascript, cordova, bluetooth-lowenergy

We have a device that connects using BLE.

The first connection is successful.

But when the signal is lost, reconnection does not happen

Connected:

```
ble.connect (deviceAddress, connectSuccess, connectFailed);
```

If the connection is successful, I add an event to the button

```
function connectSuccess (characteristic) {
    log ("connectSuccess to" + characteristic.name);

    var fieldState = document.getElementById ("fieldState");
    fieldState.addEventListener ("click",
        function () {readData (uuids1.StateState, "field State", "textField"); });
}
```

When the connection fails, I interrogate the device every 10 seconds

```
function connectFailed (characteristic) {
    log ("connectFailed to" + characteristic.name);
    ble.disconnect (deviceAddress);
    reconnect = setTimeout (function tryToBack () {
        ble.connect (deviceAddress, sc, connectFailed);
        log ("Try Connecting !!");
        reconnect = setTimeout (tryToBack, 10000);
        },
    100);
}

function sc (data) {
    clearTimeout (reconnect);
    log ("Success reconnect to" + data.name);
    log ("with address" + deviceAddress);
    connectSuccess (data)
}
```

But when the device is in sight, it is connected but does not respond to a button click.